# how to get the attribute value as text in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make a jquery slideUp/slideDown when you click on a Menu item in the menu. I thought that I could do this by doing a conditional based on the value of the display attribute, but for some reason its not working. I must not be getting the attribute value correctly, what am I doing wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#left-help-menu li").click(function() {
    if($(this).children().attr('display') == 'none')
    {   
        $(this).children().css('display', 'block');
    }
    else if($(this).children().attr('display') == 'block')
    {
        $(this).children().css('display', 'none');
    }
});
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`display` is not an attribute on the html-object. You need to check the value that you are setting with css on the next line:

```
if($(this).children().css('display') == 'none') {   
    $(this).children().css('display', 'block');
}
```

Better yet:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#left-help-menu li").click(function() {
        $(this).children().toggle();
    });
})
```

EDIT: Same code with comments and variables for clarity

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // When all the html has been loaded we locate all the <li> tags
    var $lis = $("#left-help-menu li");

    // After that we bind the click event on them to an anonymous function
    $lis.click(function() {

        // Whenever a <li> is clicked this code will run.

        // First, lets get a hold of the clicked element
        var $li = $(this);

        // Now, find all the elements in that <li>
        $children = $li.children();

        // Lastly, lets hide or show them
        $children.toggle();
    });
})
```

Note: This does not actually make the content of the `<li>` "slide" up/down. If you want that you could use the [`$.slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) method.

Comment: For some reason, neither of these options is working properly. The first suggestion at first did nothing. I did a check and saw that the default display wasn't block but inline. When I changed the code, now when you click on the menu items, the entire menu item dissapears. In the second suggestion, when you click on the menu, the menu items appear but the menu item disappers...

Comment: Ok. It's hard to tell exactly what is happening without seeing your html and css. Whatever the case is `$.toggle()` will probably help you out. It simply shows/hides the elements using the css attribute `display`. If you have other css (like `visibility` and stuff) you might run into trouble. I'll edit my answer with some comments and variable names and maybe you can figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`display` is a style not attribute. Change `.attr()` to `.css()`

Try this,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#left-help-menu li").click(function() {
    if($(this).children().css('display') == 'none')
    {   
        $(this).children().css('display', 'block');
    }
    else if($(this).children().css('display') == 'block')
    {
        $(this).children().css('display', 'none');
    }
  });
})
```